# Initialization Error when going to Civi CRM dashboard and adding pages/posts

Tags: database

I've had Civi CRM integrated in my website for a couple years no with no issues. However recently I've not been able to update any pages or posts or even go into the Civi CRM dashboard. All that shows is this error:

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -26
    [message] => DB Error: insufficient permissions
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] =>  [nativecode=1044 ** Access denied for user 'rcboa171_civicrm'@'localhost' to database 'rcboa171_saveskahapark_civicrm']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  [nativecode=1044 ** Access denied for user 'rcboa171_civicrm'@'localhost' to database 'rcboa171_saveskahapark_civicrm']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: insufficient permissions" code=-26 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=1044 ** Access denied for user 'rcboa171_civicrm'@'localhost' to database 'rcboa171_saveskahapark_civicrm']"]
)
```

Although my pages view fine from the front end and I can upload media.

Has anyone seen this before? Why would this be happening now? I haven't done any updates to my database or touched/changed anything in the last few months as it's pretty big site and I'm worried about updating the plugin or cms.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CiviCRM is unable to access the CiviCRM database.  This is often separate from the content management system database (i.e. the database for WordPress, Drupal or Joomla).  This means that you may be able to access and log in to your website, but not access CiviCRM.

I'm not sure why this has happened in your case but I would suggest that you check your hosting package and see if there have been any changes to the databases or database users.  You should also check that the database settings in your CiviCRM settings file are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply William. I've been trying to look through the database and contact my hosting provider with no luck on seeing what the problem is. On my hosting I only have my one database related to the site and not the rcboa171_saveskahapark_civicrm database. If that was somehow deleted (which I wouldn't know how that happened!) this is the error I would be getting hey? I have a backup from earlier in the year so will try to see what that one looks like.